# How to open bootstrap modal automatically in ie8?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to open a Bootstrap modal box in IE 8, its not getting opened automatically. 
Following is the code which am using.

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sampModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        show : true
    }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="sampModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sampModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If someone have same issue. Please help.

Comment: As you can see (using syntax highlighting which your editor surely does?) you're missing a `'` after your ID and before the parenthesis. Your console would tell you the same. This would not work on *any* browser.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. When i copied to stack, i missed that. In my code its correct $('#sampModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        show : true
    });
I just edited in question

Comment: OK can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Hari answer updated with a jsFiddle

Comment: Found the issue. This is not bootstrap problem or any code issue. There was another script which was failing only in IE 8, so this modal script is not rendering properly. Since i was working in IE 8 there was no error console to find this error.

Bootstrap modal is working fine in IE 8 too.
Thanks for all you comments friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

Because OP mentioned that there is nothing wrong with the syntax.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/792RD/) is a jsFilddle containing the same exact code you are using. It is working perfectly on IE8 (aside for the styling cause by the lack of CSS3 properties support). To see it on IE8 please go to [this result page](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/792RD/embedded/result/) on IE8, the modal fires perfectly

---

As [h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800909/how-to-open-bootstrap-modal-automatically-in-ie8#comment36610753_23800909) commented, you have a missing `'` in your selector `$('#sampModal)`

This question is a bad example of how people who do not understand the basic of seeking help. In the future please:

- If you are facing a JavaScript problem, make sure the code you post is valid.
- Check the console if it has any logs / errors / messages and post it.
- Post a JsFiddle that produces the error. Maybe the error is due to something else in your script or maybe you are calling the modal HTML using Ajax so on document ready event isn't applicable at this time.
- Provide more information about the libraries you are using. On this example, OP doesn't state is he using Bootstrap 2 or 3? Is he using jQuery 1.x or 2?

More information about [How to ask questions and seek help on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I just wanted to clarify these points for you and for others. Thanks to [h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800909/how-to-open-bootstrap-modal-automatically-in-ie8#comment36610753_23800909) for noticing the missing `'`

Comment: Maybe you could update your excelent answer to include a link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and/or http://www.sscce.org/?

Comment: @Potherca Thanks for the link and the compliment :)

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. When i copied to stack, i missed that. I just edited in my question.

Comment: This problem is only in IE 8. Its working fine in IE 9 & chrome.

Comment: @Hari What does your console say? What version of jQuery are you using? ([jQuery 2.x only supports IE 9+](http://jquery.com/browser-support/))

Answer (score -2):

I was asked to explain why this works. I don't know. It just does. Yours doesn't. So this answer is the solution to your problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sampModal').modal('show'); 
});
```

Comment: It's better if you explain *why* your code solves the problem. See [answer].